# Supply password to SSH on Windows without Putty

Tags: windows, powershell, ssh

I need to pass a password to my ssh connection from Windows. I cannot use things like Putty or just use a key file.

```
ssh user@ip -p "password"
```

Is it possible to do this without an external module, perhaps by pressing the keys programmatically?

Comment: Depends on what version of powershell you are using. Can you get us some more information on what you are trying to accomplish and what kind of errors you are having?

Answer (score 3):

If you need to connect to a server programmatically, you must use a public-private key pair.

Run the following on your windows machine:

```
ssh-keygen
```

Hit enter to use default path and leave the passprase blank.
Two files will be generated: id_rsa (private key) and id_rsa.pub (public key).

Copy the public key to the server.

```
scp .ssh/id_rsa.pub user@ip:
```

Then log into the server and add the public key to ssh authorization file.

```
cat id_rsa.pub >> .ssh/authorized_keys
```

And that's all. Now you should be able to log into the server from your windows machine without entering any password.

Answer (score 0):

You need to activate the ssh optional feature in windows.

Go to **Settings > Apps** and click **“Manage optional features”** under **Apps & features**. A list of optional features will be displayed.

Just click on install over the **“OpenSSH Client (Beta)”**  element.

After installation, you will be able to shh with cmd or powershell console, i.e., no external programs like putty will be required.

Source: https://www.howtogeek.com/336775/how-to-enable-and-use-windows-10s-built-in-ssh-commands/